# VBA on Internet Explorer

Tags: html, css, excel, vba, internet-explorer

I'm trying to automate a process in a intranet website using VBA and Internet Explorer.

The first to do is click on a "button" that acess another screen in the intranet, but i've already tried a lot of ways to do that, but without success. Can you help me to learn how to click on this button?

I've alread tried the way with querySelector and trying to search the style, stating span, but I've more "buttons" with the same style, and that does not work.

The code can compile, in both ways above, but, in IE screen, not happens...

```
<span style="font-weight: normal; font-family: Arial; font-size: 9pt; 
 font style: normal; text-decoration: none;">Invoiced<img alt="" 
   src="/QvAjaxZfc/QvsViewClient.aspx?datamode=binary&amp;name=LED&amp;host=QVS%40cbrcur01apcp480&amp;slot=&amp;public=only&amp;color=%2300f010&amp;xrfkey=nEDfFknqkhWgtMq9" 
 class="icon" style="height: 10px; width: 10px;"> 
 </span>
```

There is a Javascript that it can be able to click, too, the code is show below:

```
<li id="Document\SH05" rel="DocumentSH05" order="1" style="display: list-item;"> <a href="javascript:;" 
style="color: rgb(255, 255, 255); background: rgb(175, 40, 63);"> 
<span style="font-weight: normal; font-family: Arial; font- size: 9pt; font-style: normal; text-decoration: none;">
Invoiced<img alt="" src="/QvAjaxZfc/QvsViewClient.aspx?datamode=binary&amp;name=LED&amp;host=QVS%40cbrcur01apcp480&amp;
slot=&amp;public=only&amp;
color=%2300f010&amp;xrfkey=nEDfFknqkhWgtMq9" class="icon" style="height: 10px; width: 10px;"></span></a></li>
```

I need to click on the button, but now, I'dont have any results.

my current code is:

```
Sub demo()

Dim IE As InternetExplorerMedium
Dim html As HTMLDocument

Set IE = New InternetExplorer
IE.Visible = True
IE.Navigate2 "Example"

Do While IE.Busy
    Application.Wait DateAdd("s", 1, Now)
Loop

'IE.document.getElementById("Document\SH08").Click
Set valores = IE.document.getElementsByTagName("li")
For Each valor In valores
    If valor.getAttribute("id") = "Document\SH05" Then
        valor.Click
    Exit For
 End If
Next valor
```

End Sub

Comment: Show some code don't just post the entire story

Comment: If possible please show your HTML code. Than we can try to make a test with it and try to provide you some suggestions to click that button. Code can help us to understand the issue in better way. Thanks for your understanding.

Comment: I'm sorry, im new here. kkk

Comment: please yse [edit] to add your current code.

Comment: have you tried ie.document.querySelector("[rel='DocumentSH05'] a").click  ?

Comment: yes, it didn't work. I think the website is in a kind of javascript. Do somebody know how to click on a javascript button?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution. I did install the Selenium library for VBA and changed the InternetExplorer for Chrome.

Now, I click on the respective link with the Xpatch (driver.FindElementByXPath("XPATCH").Click).

Worked like a charm!

Thanks!!

Comment: Thanks for posting the solution for this issue. I suggest you to try to mark your own answer as an accepted answer for this question after 48 hrs, when it is available to mark. It can help other community members in future in similar kind of issues. Thanks for your understanding.

Answer (score 0):

try to refer an example below may solve your issue.

```
Sub demo()

    Dim IE As InternetExplorer
    Dim html As HTMLDocument

    Set IE = New InternetExplorerMedium
    IE.Visible = True
    IE.Navigate2 "D:\Backup20190913\tests\265.html"

    Do While IE.Busy
        Application.Wait DateAdd("s", 1, Now)
    Loop
   Dim objTag As Object
    For Each objTag In IE.document.getElementsByTagName("span")
    If InStr(objTag.outerHTML, "Invoiced") > 0 Then

        objTag.Click
        Exit For

    End If
Next
    Stop
    IE.Quit
    Set IE = Nothing

End Sub
```

It is able to click your span tag.

Output:

[image]

Comment: Thanks Deepak, but it didn't work... my code run, but nothing happen on the screen...

Comment: You need to put break point and debug your code step by step to check whether it is able to find the span tag and clicking it or not.

Comment: Yes! I add more information on the topic. I'm new on HTML, i don't know if it's necessary to declare everything...

Comment: Try to click the LI tag using it's id to check whether it helps to click the button or not.

Comment: I debugged the code and the vba found the ID, but the click doesn't work!

Comment: Can you please inform us the result of debugging the above posted code? Does that code able to correct span element and is it clicking it? If it is public site than you can also try to share the address of the site. than we can try to test the issue with the site.

Comment: Deepak, it's not a public site, it's a company intranet, unfortunately... I changed the InternetExplorer to Chrome and it worked like a charm! Thank you.